# C++ function object to return `p->first` and `p->second`

Tags: c++, boost, stl

Is there a builtin function object that returns `p->first` and `p->second`, so that I can happily write

```
transform(m.begin(),m.end(),back_inserter(keys),get_first);
transform(m.begin(),m.end(),back_inserter(vals),get_second);
```

STL-based solution is the best, `boost` solution is second best.

Yeah, I know `boost::lambda`, I don't want to start using it.

Comment: It seems you've realised that no direct support exists in the STL (or presumably boost), why not write a simple function template to do this for you? it's bound to be clearer than either the `bind` approach or the non-standard approach...

Comment: @Nim, that's probably a good idea, however I'm always afraid that everyone on the team will come up with his own version of `littleTidbitMissingFromSpec`, so if I could find something solid on boost, it would be better.

Comment: a well documented utils (or aux) namespace is what you need! ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are nonstandard extensions to [`g++`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man3/__gnu_cxx::select1st.3.html) and [`SGI`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/select1st.html) called `select1st` and `select2nd`. So there's probably nothing in the STL for that.

Boost's bind can also do that, give it a pointer to the correct member function

```
boost::bind(&std::map<string,string>::value_type::second,_1)
```

Answer (score 5):

We can easily write a select1st and select2nd:

```
struct select1st
{
   template< typename K, typename V >
   const K& operator()( std::pair<K,V> const& p ) const
   {
       return p.first;
   }
};

struct select2nd
{
   template< typename K, typename V >
   const V& operator()( std::pair<K,V> const& p ) const
   {
       return p.second;
   }
};
```

Here is an alternative, actually more flexible version:

```
struct select1st
{
   template< typename P >
   typename P::first_type const& operator()( P const& p ) const
   {
       return p.first;
   }
};

struct select2nd
{
   template< typename P >
   typename P::second_type const& operator()( P const& p ) const
   {
       return p.second;
   }
};
```

subsequently:

```
transform(m.begin(),m.end(),back_inserter(keys), select1st());
transform(m.begin(),m.end(),back_inserter(vals), select2nd());
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can use C++0x you can either use real lambdas since G++ 4.5 or you can use the new tuple-library which is fully compatible with std::pairs. Then you could use std::get<0> for first and std::get<1> for second.

If you are bound to C++98 you can use std::tr1::tuple instead of std::pair, as in TR1 get doesn't work with std::pair.

Also you can use bind from TR1 (tr1/functional) like Elazar described it.