# flattening a std::map to a set via std::transform

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, c++14, stl-algorithm

I need to flatten a container from `std::map<int, std::set<std::string>>` to `std::set<std::string>` and I am running to difficulties with the syntax.  When I say flatten, I basically want to make a single `std::set<string>` with all the sets stitched together - (the `set` will prevent duplicates entries which is what I need) I was trying something based on the answer in this [**question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10916728/copy-stdmap-to-stdset-in-c) but my value type is a container which makes the problem harder to solve.  The output from the compiler is very difficult to understand, here the source is shown below.

I have a live coliru of my code [**here**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f790451888140b8d)

```
int main()
{
    std::set<std::string> outputSet;

    std::map<int, std::set<std::string>> inputMap = {
        {1, {"a", "b", "c"}},
        {2, {"b", "c", "d"}}
    };

    std::transform(inputMap.cbegin(), inputMap.cend(), 
        std::inserter(outputSet, outputSet.end()), 
        [](const std::map<int, std::set<std::string>>::value_type& rNext) {
            return rNext.second;
        });        
}
```

The errors are shown below:

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/6.2.0/algorithm:62:0,
                 from main.cpp:4:
/usr/local/include/c++/6.2.0/bits/stl_algo.h: In instantiation of '_OIter std::transform(_IIter, _IIter, _OIter, _UnaryOperation) [with _IIter = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<const int, std::set<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >; _OIter = std::insert_iterator<std::set<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; _UnaryOperation = main()::<lambda(const value_type&)>]':
main.cpp:19:10:   required from here
/usr/local/include/c++/6.2.0/bits/stl_algo.h:4177:12: error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'std::insert_iterator<std::set<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >' and 'std::set<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >')
  *__result = __unary_op(*__first);
  ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/6.2.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:67:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/6.2.0/bits/stl_tree.h:63,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/6.2.0/set:60,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/c++/6.2.0/bits/stl_iterator.h:680:7: note: candidate: std::insert_iterator<_Container>& std::insert_iterator<_Container>::operator=(const typename _Container::value_type&) [with _Container = std::set<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; typename _Container::value_type = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]
       operator=(const typename _Container::value_type& __value)
       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/c++/6.2.0/bits/stl_iterator.h:680:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::set<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >' to 'const value_type& {aka const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&}'
/usr/local/include/c++/6.2.0/bits/stl_iterator.h:688:7: note: candidate: std::insert_iterator<_Container>& std::insert_iterator<_Container>::operator=(typename _Container::value_type&&) [with _Container = std::set<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; typename _Container::value_type = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]
       operator=(typename _Container::value_type&& __value)
       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/c++/6.2.0/bits/stl_iterator.h:688:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::set<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >' to 'std::set<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::value_type&& {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&&}'
/usr/local/include/c++/6.2.0/bits/stl_iterator.h:629:11: note: candidate: constexpr std::insert_iterator<std::set<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >& std::insert_iterator<std::set<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >::operator=(const std::insert_iterator<std::set<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >&)
     class insert_iterator
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/c++/6.2.0/bits/stl_iterator.h:629:11: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::set<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >' to 'const std::insert_iterator<std::set<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >&'
/usr/local/include/c++/6.2.0/bits/stl_iterator.h:629:11: note: candidate: constexpr std::insert_iterator<std::set<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >& std::insert_iterator<std::set<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >::operator=(std::insert_iterator<std::set<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >&&)
/usr/local/include/c++/6.2.0/bits/stl_iterator.h:629:11: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::set<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >' to 'std::insert_iterator<std::set<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >&&'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`std::insert_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/insert_iterator) you're creating using `std::inserter` expects to be assigned a single element which it will then insert into the container, but you're attempting to assign an entire `set` to it.

`std::for_each` is better suited to what you're trying to do

```
std::for_each(inputMap.cbegin(), inputMap.cend(),
    [&](auto const& m) {
        outputSet.insert(m.second.begin(), m.second.end());
    });
```

Comment: Nice, elegant and simple, I figured out that the transform requiring a std::set of std::sets, see http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/391408db3b414728 where I made some changes to the coliru demo.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just do things the straight-forward way using range `for`:

```
for (const auto& v : inputMap)
    for (const auto& e : v.second)
        outputSet.insert(e);
```

that may not be super elegant; but it doesn't generate any compiler errors either.  With that working, you can adjust as necessary/desired to something else.  For example

```
for (const auto& v : inputMap)
    outputSet.insert(v.second.cbegin(), v.second.cend());
```